# Best linux distribution for machine learning

Tags: linux, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Good morning together!

Recently I tried to use a DBScan to find outliers in my data and I received a "MemoryError". It seems the implementation of scikit learn for DBScan is not very good, but anyhow I wonder how I could "solve" this issue. I was thinking if it might be helpful to run the Jupyter Notebook instead from my Windows 10 from a Linux distribution. So I googled "which linux distribution is the best for machine learning" and what I found was mostly "Ubuntu". Actually I wanted to find a linux distribution which requires lower ressources like CPU and RAM, so that the machine learning algorithm itself can use more of it.

Can anyone suggest a linux distribution which doesn't need a lot of cpu/RAM and is suitable for machine learning?

Thanks for your ideas!

I googled the question and I found distributions like "Ubuntu" which also has high requirements to the PC. Actually I wanted to find a resource saving linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Linux distros which use few resources, there's quite a number of options. People like to tweak their Arch, Gentoo, LFS, and even Slackware installs to consume as little as possible, and it's a whole hobby space. Realistically, Debian with a low-cost DE will be just fine - consider XFCE or MATE, as they're very popular for "lightweight" installs.